# Python + Selenium firefox webdriver - pulling out images out of a website

Tags: python, selenium, webdriver

I am trying to pull out images from a webpage using:
Python 2.7 + Selenium (using FireFox) + Beautiful Soup.

The page loads dynamically, hence, I'm using Selenium for screen scraping.  Everything looks great on the front end, however, when all the images I loaded, and I look at the HTML, I can't see the links to the images.  Any ideas what could be going on here?

Site is https://flipp.com/flyers?postal_code=97035 ,
and from there, navigate to https://flipp.com/weekly_ad/1550082-big-5-sporting-goods-weekly-ad in order to see the first weekly ad (My working Code is below).

To make things even more weird, I'm able to see that the images ARE loading in the inspector window... But I still can't see them in the HTML.  Any idea on whats going on here, and how to grab the updated HTML (after images load?)

Here is the set of images i am able to pull from HTML (by appending jpg).  These are just for popup windows for when you hover over the canvas.

[image]

What I am trying to get to are actually the images that make up the actual pages/canvas.  I can see them come through (using traffic option in firefox), but they are not appearing in HTML for some reason.  Any idea whats going on here?

[image]

Working code:

```
#import packages
from time import gmtime, strftime,sleep, time
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.proxy import Proxy, ProxyType
from selenium.webdriver.common.desired_capabilities import DesiredCapabilities
#scraping packages
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup


USAPROXY = "177.84.23.122:3128"
def launch_webdriver(PROXY):
    PROXY = PROXY
    PROXY_HOST = PROXY.rpartition(':')[0]
    PROXY_PORT = PROXY.rpartition(':')[2]
    fp = webdriver.FirefoxProfile()
    # Direct = 0, Manual = 1, PAC = 2, AUTODETECT = 4, SYSTEM = 5
    fp.set_preference("network.proxy.type", 1)
    fp.set_preference("network.proxy.http",PROXY_HOST)
    fp.set_preference("network.proxy.http_port",int(PROXY_PORT))
    fp.set_preference("network.proxy.ssl",PROXY_HOST)
    fp.set_preference("network.proxy.ssl_port",int(PROXY_PORT))
    fp.set_preference("general.useragent.override","whater_useragent")    
    fp.update_preferences()
    return webdriver.Firefox(firefox_profile=fp)




def test():
    driver = launch_webdriver(USAPROXY)
    driver.set_page_load_timeout(11)
    driver.get("https://flipp.com/flyers?postal_code=97035")
    sleep(15)
    driver.get("https://flipp.com/weekly_ad/1550082-big-5-sporting-goods-weekly-ad")
    sleep(5)
    my_html = driver.page_source
    soup = BeautifulSoup(my_html,'lxml')
    tags=soup.findAll('img')  #prints only 3 imgs, there should be 100s
    for tag in tags:print tag
    print soup.prettify()
#execute script
test()
```

Comment: The image is most likely assigned via CSS. Check the `background-image` in the `Computed` tab once the element is selected. If it's the case use `element.value_of_css_property('background-image')` to get the source.

Answer (score 1):

The reason why you don't see the updated **HTML** in your `my_html=driver.page_source` is because the `page_source` grabs the **HTML** before your page has **dynamically** loaded. Try this instead to get the HTML after the page has loaded:

```
my_html = driver.execute_script("return document.getElementsByTagName('html')[0].innerHTML")
# or
my_html = driver.find_element_by_tag_name('html').get_attribute('innerHTML')
```

---

EDIT:

Okay, I think I came up with what you are looking for. I found a way to access the `network` resources and get the **performance** data that the browser is logging. Call this function and pass the driver once it has loaded the page you want, and it should return the images in the format you're looking for:

```
def getNetworkImages(driver):
    ImageList = []
    Resources = driver.execute_script("return window.performance.getEntriesByType('resource');")
    for resource in Resources:
        if resource['initiatorType'] == 'img': ImageList.append(resource['name'])
    for image in ImageList: print(image)
    return ImageList
```

Note: This was tested with Chrome `64` and Chromedriver `2.35`.

Comment: Hi, no dice.  
I put in a sleep in there to wait for HTML to load, and also tried your method.  Same result.  
Images should be loading in the following format:  https://f.wishabi.net/flyers/319cafbc-e857-44fd-bd01-3a3864506e54/3_4_4.jpg    , but HTML shows nothing of that sort.

Comment: Interesting, when I use the above method I can see all the images, they are under href="" and do not have the base_url.

Comment: AH!  yes.  Those are different images from the actual background images (those are popup images). 

What I'm trying to get is the background images from the site that make up the pages

Comment: Huh, I guess I am confused. Can you post the HTML from doing an inspection on the image you are interested in?

Comment: thanks for the help.  I added two screenshots.  One is of what you are probably seeing (the images that popup when you hover over the page), and second one is of images i am trying to get, but that aren't showing up in html.  But I'm seeing them on my computer, so obviously there should be a way to extract them?

Comment: @MichelleB., I think I figured out a way to log those network loads in **chrome** if you interested in this still.

Answer (score 0):

I did a small change in your code replacing `soup = BeautifulSoup(my_html,'lxml')` with `soup = BeautifulSoup(my_html,'html.parser')` as follows :

- Code :

  ```
  driver.set_page_load_timeout(11)
  driver.get("https://flipp.com/flyers?postal_code=97035")
  sleep(15)
  driver.get("https://flipp.com/weekly_ad/1550082-big-5-sporting-goods-weekly-ad")
  sleep(5)
  my_html = driver.page_source
  soup = BeautifulSoup(my_html,'html.parser')
  tags=soup.findAll('img')
  for tag in tags:print (tag)
  ```
- Output :

  ```
  <img alt="" src="/94815ec0/images/page-favourites.svg"/>
  <img alt="" src="/94815ec0/images/page-flyers.svg"/>
  <img alt="" src="/94815ec0/images/page-coupons.svg"/>
  <img alt="" src="/94815ec0/images/profile.png"/>
  <img alt="" src="/94815ec0/images/signin-google-en.png"/>
  <img alt="" src="/94815ec0/images/signin-facebook-en.png"/>
  <img alt="" class="sl-icon" src="/94815ec0/images/sl/list-icon.svg"/>
  <img alt="" class="logo" contain="true" fit="" href="https://images.wishabi.net/merchants/2143/1399408035/large" is="flipp-lazy-image" src="data:image/png;base64,iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgAAAAEAAAABCAQAAAC1HAwCAAAAC0lEQVQYV2NgYAAAAAMAAWgmWQ0AAAAASUVORK5CYII=" style='background-image: url("https://images.wishabi.net/merchants/2143/1399408035/large");'/>
  <img src="/94815ec0/images/location.svg"/>
  <img alt="" class="flyer-thumbnail" cover="true" fit="" href="https://f.wishabi.net/flyers/1568365/web_premium/1519664612.jpg" is="flipp-lazy-image" src="data:image/png;base64,iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgAAAAEAAAABCAQAAAC1HAwCAAAAC0lEQVQYV2NgYAAAAAMAAWgmWQ0AAAAASUVORK5CYII=" style='background-image: url("https://f.wishabi.net/flyers/1568365/web_premium/1519664612.jpg");'/>
  <img alt="" class="logo" contain="true" fit="" href="https://images.wishabi.net/merchants/1417562816/1417562816/large" is="flipp-lazy-image" src="data:image/png;base64,iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgAAAAEAAAABCAQAAAC1HAwCAAAAC0lEQVQYV2NgYAAAAAMAAWgmWQ0AAAAASUVORK5CYII=" style='background-image: url("https://images.wishabi.net/merchants/1417562816/1417562816/large");'/>
  <img alt="" class="flyer-thumbnail" cover="true" fit="" href="https://f.wishabi.net/flyers/1570217/web_premium/1519767026.jpg" is="flipp-lazy-image" src="data:image/png;base64,iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgAAAAEAAAABCAQAAAC1HAwCAAAAC0lEQVQYV2NgYAAAAAMAAWgmWQ0AAAAASUVORK5CYII=" style='background-image: url("https://f.wishabi.net/flyers/1570217/web_premium/1519767026.jpg");'/>
  <img alt="" class="logo" contain="true" fit="" href="https://images.wishabi.net/merchants/2217/1399408048/large" is="flipp-lazy-image" src="data:image/png;base64,iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgAAAAEAAAABCAQAAAC1HAwCAAAAC0lEQVQYV2NgYAAAAAMAAWgmWQ0AAAAASUVORK5CYII=" style='background-image: url("https://images.wishabi.net/merchants/2217/1399408048/large");'/>
  <img alt="" class="flyer-thumbnail" cover="true" fit="" href="https://f.wishabi.net/flyers/1548763/web_premium/1519408077.jpg" is="flipp-lazy-image" src="data:image/png;base64,iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgAAAAEAAAABCAQAAAC1HAwCAAAAC0lEQVQYV2NgYAAAAAMAAWgmWQ0AAAAASUVORK5CYII=" style='background-image: url("https://f.wishabi.net/flyers/1548763/web_premium/1519408077.jpg");'/>
  <img alt="" class="logo" contain="true" fit="" href="https://images.wishabi.net/merchants/2392/1412008375/large" is="flipp-lazy-image" src="data:image/png;base64,iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgAAAAEAAAABCAQAAAC1HAwCAAAAC0lEQVQYV2NgYAAAAAMAAWgmWQ0AAAAASUVORK5CYII=" style='background-image: url("https://images.wishabi.net/merchants/2392/1412008375/large");'/>
  <img alt="" class="flyer-thumbnail" cover="true" fit="" href="https://f.wishabi.net/flyers/1558209/web_premium/1519940192.jpg" is="flipp-lazy-image" src="data:image/png;base64,iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgAAAAEAAAABCAQAAAC1HAwCAAAAC0lEQVQYV2NgYAAAAAMAAWgmWQ0AAAAASUVORK5CYII=" style='background-image: url("https://f.wishabi.net/flyers/1558209/web_premium/1519940192.jpg");'/>
  <img alt="" class="logo" contain="true" fit="" href="https://images.wishabi.net/merchants/2175/1399558010/large" is="flipp-lazy-image" src="data:image/png;base64,iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgAAAAEAAAABCAQAAAC1HAwCAAAAC0lEQVQYV2NgYAAAAAMAAWgmWQ0AAAAASUVORK5CYII=" style='background-image: url("https://images.wishabi.net/merchants/2175/1399558010/large");'/>
  <img alt="" class="flyer-thumbnail" cover="true" fit="" href="https://f.wishabi.net/flyers/1553653/web_premium/1519086192.jpg" is="flipp-lazy-image" src="data:image/png;base64,iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgAAAAEAAAABCAQAAAC1HAwCAAAAC0lEQVQYV2NgYAAAAAMAAWgmWQ0AAAAASUVORK5CYII=" style='background-image: url("https://f.wishabi.net/flyers/1553653/web_premium/1519086192.jpg");'/>
  <img alt="" class="logo" contain="true" fit="" href="https://images.wishabi.net/merchants/1415661435/1415661435/large" is="flipp-lazy-image" src="data:image/png;base64,iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgAAAAEAAAABCAQAAAC1HAwCAAAAC0lEQVQYV2NgYAAAAAMAAWgmWQ0AAAAASUVORK5CYII=" style='background-image: url("https://images.wishabi.net/merchants/1415661435/1415661435/large");'/>
  <img alt="" src="/94815ec0/images/email_notices.png"/>
  <img alt="Flipp logo"/>
  <img alt="image of a sad ice cream" class="sad-cream"/>
  <img alt="Google Chrome Logo" class="browser-img chrome"/>
  <img alt="Mozilla Firefox Logo" class="browser-img ff"/>
  <img alt="Microsoft Edge Logo" class="browser-img edge"/>
  <img alt="Apple Safari Logo" class="browser-img safari"/>
  <img alt="" height="0" id="batBeacon0.08041384361820791" src="https://bat.bing.com/action/0?ti=5463843&amp;Ver=2&amp;mid=e698c347-3982-6279-c6a5-5e5b764b55dd&amp;evt=pageLoad&amp;sid=ab7428c0-1&amp;lt=1647&amp;pi=0&amp;lg=en-US&amp;sw=1366&amp;sh=768&amp;sc=24&amp;tl=Big%205%20Sporting%20Goods%20Weekly%20Ad%20for%20Lake%20Oswego%20this%20week%20(Feb%2025,%202018%20-%20Mar%203,%202018)%20-%20Flipp&amp;kw=flyers,%20coupons,%20shopping%20list,%20deals,%20circulaires,%20coupons,%20liste%20d%E2%80%99achats,%20offres&amp;p=https%3A%2F%2Fflipp.com%2Fweekly_ad%2F1550082-big-5-sporting-goods-weekly-ad&amp;r=&amp;msclkid=N&amp;rn=558478" style="width:0px; height:0px; display:none; visibility:hidden;" width="0"/>
  ```

Comment: Hi!  Thanks for the try -  I am able to see these images as well.  If you check out my second screenshot - there is a set of images in the following format- https://f.wishabi.net/flyers/319cafbc-e857-44fd-bd01-3a3864506e54/3_1_3.jpg

note, there is a few hundred of them, and only thing that changes is 3_1_3.jpg portion (the numbers change up).    I am able to see those come through via network inspector in firefox, however, they are not appearing in the html for some reason?  any thought on whats going on here?